# Otto event bus receiving multiple events on single post

Tags: android, dagger, otto

I am using Otto and Dagger. Some of my events are being received multiple times on only one post.

In my view that posts the event:

`@Inject Bus mBus;`

In the constructor:

```
((MyApplication) mContext.getApplicationContext()).inject(this);  

view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(final View view) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Sending SearchResultClickedEvent.");
    mBus.post(new SearchResultClickedEvent(mModel.getPlaceId()));
  }
});
```

In the super class for my subscribing activity:

`@Inject protected Bus mBus;`

In the `onCreate()`:

`((HarryApplication) getApplicationContext()).inject(this);`

In the subscribing activity:

```
@Subscribe
public void on(SearchResultsRecyclerViewHolder.SearchResultClickedEvent event) {
  Log.d(TAG, "SearchResultClickedEvent received.");
}
```

The logs after a single click:

```
03-26 12:59:51.496  24613-24613/D/SearchResultView﹕ Sending SearchResultClickedEvent.
03-26 12:59:51.496  24613-24613/D/Subscriber﹕SearchResultClickedEvent received.
03-26 12:59:51.497  24613-24613/D/Subscriber﹕SearchResultClickedEvent received.
03-26 12:59:51.499  24613-24613/D/Subscriber﹕SearchResultClickedEvent received.
```

Comment: is there any chance you have your activity leaked and you have multiple receivers registered. Please show us how you subscribe & unsubscribe from the bus?

Comment: Ah thank you! I didn't know we had to unregister. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was not unregistering my event bus object.

Added this and it works as expected:

```
  @Override protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mBus.unregister(this);
  }
```

Comment: THANK YOU. I meet the same problem, I thought it was memory leak until I read your answer.